# Watson swift SDK for Objective-C bridging for Speech to Text

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, watson

Watson swift SDK for Objective-C bridging for Speech to Text

I am doing iOS app which is Objective-C language. In that, We are using Watson SDK which is also Objective-C version, but recently we are getting issues on that SDK, after that, we approached that SDK team, they said it's deprecated, and try to integrate Swift version SDK. Now, We are integrating Swift version of Watson SDK.

We successfully integrated for Text To Speech by following link by doing Bridging.

I want to make this method which is requirement of my application for Objective-C bridging.

```
    // start recognize 
[stt recognize:^(NSDictionary* res, NSError* err){

if(res == nil && err == nil){  
 return;
  }
if(err == nil) {
if([self.stt isFinalTranscript:res]) {


}

} dataHandler:^(NSData* data) {


} powerHandler:^(float power) {

}];
```

// The above method exactly in SDK file of Speech to Text

```
- (void) recognize:(void (^)(NSDictionary*, NSError*)) recognizeHandler dataHandler: (void (^) (NSData*)) dataHandler powerHandler: (void (^)(float)) powerHandler {
```

https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/swift-sdk/blob/master/docs/objective-c.md

But, strucked with Speech to Text integration, Can anyone have idea about above code.

Comment: strucked with Speech to Text integration --- ? in which place you struck

Comment: we have method             [stt recognize:^(NSDictionary* res, NSError* err){
and inside this call back methods of Watson SDK functionality.

Comment: what the issu u faced

Comment: I did not found that method in swift version, did u used bridging for objective-C for Watson SDK

Comment: i am not used Watson before but we can try , and u tried the sample code of swift

Comment: so, can you help for that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152520/discussion-between-anilkumar-ios-developer-and-anbu-karthik).

Comment: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/swift-sdk#transcribe-microphone-audio  - can you use this example?  The failure callback should be called if no audio is detected.

Comment: If you want to adjust the timeout, set the inactivity timeout setting. - https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/swift-sdk/blob/master/Source/SpeechToTextV1/Models/RecognitionSettings.swift#L37-L39

Comment: @bob.faist Thanks so much for your response, I added bridge for Objective-C project to adding Watson SDK swift version, but how can I call startStreaming method to my objective-c class? and failure, stop recognising audio and get final speech data? can you help me this way?